# Can I "Speed Up" a VM to emulate the passage of time?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, ubuntu-12.04

I'd like to put a VM into "fast forward" so that I can see several days (or weeks, or months) worth of logs and temp files build up and analyse them.

Is that possible with virtualbox & ubuntu 12.04 VM?

Comment: I doubt it's possible :-(

Comment: Just open the computer to the Internet and watch the logs fill and your hair grow whiter.

Comment: The docs here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html in section 9.11 talk about some related parameters, like "WarpDrivePercentage".  However, my results were pretty mixed.  Audio sounded like it was getting jumped forwards a dozen times a second, yielding the right speedup and approximately (but not really) the right effect, but "sleep 10" slept a full 10 seconds, and the clock kept pace with the wall clock.  I tried several variations, but didn't get it working quite right.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it can be done by playing with the jiffies in the kernel, by adding a speedup ratio. There is a [document with a presentation about a quick 10 year test](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://elinux.org/images/6/6d/Linux_Kernel_Acceleration_for_Long-term_Testing.pdf&ei=FsrjUZa6D4f07AaO6ICYCA&usg=AFQjCNEBSbM8joR_BBe9NNT8MfSheSL51Q&sig2=VINymA2GASu2C5DSJJoVRQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZGU). It boils down to this:

Add a parameter to Kconfig (SPEEDUP_RATIO, ~1-1000), modify do_timer():

```
 void do_timer(...) {
        jiffies_64 = jiffies_64 + speedup_ratio;
    }
```

Finally, control ratio via procfs (`echo 100 > /proc/accel`). Then he had lots of timeouts on boot and had to adjust all the timeouts in the kernel (timeout * speedup_ratio). He says most of these values can be found with `grep jiffies`, but the "most" means it may involve some trial and error.

Also, according to `man 7 time`: "The size of a jiffy is determined by the value of the kernel constant HZ". It is configurable, but only takes the values 100, 250, 300 and 1000.

**EDIT**: If time leaps are acceptable, [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) may be a much simpler alternative. But I don't know how logging software will deal with that.